# Linear subspace invariance and matrices in particular relation

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider two matrices $A\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $B\in GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ such that $$A^{25}=AB^{24}+BA^{24}$$
I want to prove that the image of $A$ is $B-$invariant, i.e. $B(Im(A))\subseteq Im(A).$

I have a solution if $A$ is invertible: from the given relation
$$BA^{24}=A^{25}-AB^{24}\Rightarrow BA=A(A-AB^{24}A^{-23}),$$
which implies the invariance.
I don’t get a solution if $A$ is not invertible: I don’t know if this can be useful, but $A-B$ is invertible: we immediately see that
$$(A-B)(A^{24}-B^{24})=B^{25}$$
and since $B$ is invertible we have that $A-B$ is invertible, with inverse
$$(A-B)^{-1}=(A^{24}-B^{24})B^{-25}=A^{24}B^{-25}-B^{-1}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say, $A-B$ is invertible.  Now notice that we have $AB^{24}=(A-B)A^{24}$.  Since $A-B$ and $B^{24}$ are invertible, we conclude that $\ker A$ and $\ker A^{24}$ have the same dimension.  This implies that $\operatorname{im}(A)=\operatorname{im}(A^{24})$ (since $\operatorname{im}(A^{24})\subseteq \operatorname{im}(A)$ but they have the same dimension, namely, $n-\dim\ker A=n-\dim\ker A^{24})$.  But now note that the equation $BA^{24}=A^{25}-AB^{24}$ implies that $B(\operatorname{im}(A^{24}))\subseteq \operatorname{im}(A)$ and thus $B(\operatorname{im}(A))\subseteq \operatorname{im}(A)$.